# Working with Classes and types

Tags: c++

I am trying to try this new project out that I was introduced to a while back but I am not sure what is going on here. I am sure that I can store an int in an int varible but it is telling me that I can't convert from int to student and I am not sure what it is trying to tell me. Can someone here please explain to me what exactly this is trying to tell me or what I am missing?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class student
{
public:
    int id;            //student ID number
    string name;       //student’s name
    string university; //student’ university
};


//student list is a doubly linked list of students. 
class studentList
{
private:
    class node
    {
    public:
        student data;
        node * next;
        node * prev;
    };

    node * head;

public:
    studentList()
    {
        head = NULL;
    }

    //be sure to free all dynamically allocated memory!
    ~studentList();

    //return true if the list is empty, false if not
    bool empty()
    {
        if(head == NULL)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    };

    //insert student s into the front of the linked list
    void push(student s)
    {
        node * nodeptr;
        nodeptr = new node();
        nodeptr->data = s;
        nodeptr->next = head;
        head = nodeptr;
        nodeptr->prev = head;
        if (nodeptr->next != NULL)
            nodeptr->next->prev = nodeptr;
    };

    //remove and return the student at the front of the list
    student pop()
    {
        node * nodeptr;
        int y;
        nodeptr = head;
        if (head->next != NULL)
            head->next->prev = head;
        head = head->next;
        y = nodeptr->data.id;
        delete nodeptr;
        return y;
    };

    //locate and remove the student with given ID number
    void removeStudent(int id);

    //locate and return a copy of the student with given ID number
    student getStudent(int id);

    //arrange students into increasing based on either ID or name.  If
    //variable 'field' has value "id", sort into increasing order by id.
    //If 'field' has value "name", sort into alphabetical order by name.
    void sort(string field);

    //a test function to simply display the list of students to the screen
    //in the order they appear in the list.
    void display();
};
```

Comment: When posting to StackOverflow, in the case of a compile error, you should include the actual compiler error and, if possible, an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `student pop()` function

```
student pop()
{
    node * nodeptr;
    int y;
    nodeptr = head;
    if (head->next != NULL)
        head->next->prev = head;
    head = head->next;
    y = nodeptr->data.id;
    delete nodeptr;
    return y;
};
```

You are trying to return an `int y` where as you said the return type should be type `student` so if you would like to return `int y` then you should change this to

```
int pop()
{
    node * nodeptr;
    int y;
    nodeptr = head;
    if (head->next != NULL)
        head->next->prev = head;
    head = head->next;
    y = nodeptr->data.id;
    delete nodeptr;
    return y;
};
```

if you want to return the student you can do this

```
student pop()
{
    node * nodeptr;
    student y;
    nodeptr = head;
    if (head->next != NULL)
        head->next->prev = head;
    head = head->next;
    y = nodeptr->data;
    delete nodeptr;
    return y;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare that your pop() method is returning student, however it's returning an int.

```
   student pop()
    {
        node * nodeptr;
        int y;
        nodeptr = head;
        if (head->next != NULL)
            head->next->prev = head;
        head = head->next;
        y = nodeptr->data.id;
        delete nodeptr;
        return y; // not an object of student type!!!
    };
```

You should return nodeptr instead of deleting it.

Comment: I noticed that I tried to edit the y part to say student y and it took it but what exactly am I doing there? Or so i thought

Comment: if you say `student y` then you should assign `y = nodeptr` and return it (without deleting nodeptr, of course)

Comment: Well the reason that I delete it is because I need to get rid of it according to the assignment. Not a big deal for me but they told me if I don't it would create a memory leak. Not sure if that is completely true or not..

Comment: I think you have misunderstood it a bit. It's probably the caller of student.pop () who would have to delete the result.